# LOADING MULTIPLE CSV FILE INTO SINGLE TABLE IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 31 csv file in my pc. I want to load all these csv file into a single table in mysql. is there anyway to do this using sql query??

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552042/mysql-loading-multiple-files-into-a-table or here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538995/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Use **LOAD DATA INFILE**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/part/yourfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE NameOfTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'    -- because CSV
ENCLOSED BY '"'             -- I don't know your file
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'    -- Probably this
IGNORE 1 ROWS;              -- If it has to be
```

And again for all your CSV

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pc is a windows pc, if yes then use below command one by one for each file-

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:\\temp\\your_file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

If you don't have header line then remove "IGNORE 1 LINES".

If you are using linux or mac then there will be little bit change in syntax.

Answer (score -3):

Try to first cat all of the files into a single csv

`cat file1.csv file2.csv > outputfile.csv`
or
`cat *.csv > outputfile.csv`

Then use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import outputfile.csv one time