# How to bulk insert text files into MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I just wanted to ask your expertise in bulk insert into mysql table, as of now this script is working fine:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\test\\cdr_june1.txt' INTO TABLE bod FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

But this past few days my text file have different file name, I was thinking to load all the file with .txt extension. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you should check [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370), if you want to make answering your questions so easy as possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538995/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-a-mysql-database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552042/mysql-loading-multiple-files-into-a-table